# How to return the correct List<List<Integer>> in the subset backtracking problem

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

I am approaching a problem from Leetcode (78. Subsets). The method is correct, but I can't figure out how to return the correct answer.

I used the method I learned from an online course. I could accurately print out all the subsets when reaching the base case; however, I am not sure how to add those sublists into a result `List<List<Integer>>` and return it.

I declared a global variable and try to modify it directly, but all the subsets in it are empty. What is a good way for me to add the subsets to the result list and return it?

Here's the code:

```
class Solution {

    List<List<Integer>> result;

    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<Integer> chosen = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i : nums){
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        subsetsHelper(numbers, chosen);
        return result;
    }

    public void subsetsHelper(List<Integer> nums, List<Integer> chosen){
        if (nums.size() == 0){
            // System.out.println(chosen);
            result.add(chosen);
        }
        else{
            int x = nums.get(0);
            nums.remove(0);

            subsetsHelper(nums, chosen);

            chosen.add(x);
            subsetsHelper(nums, chosen);

            nums.add(0, x);
            chosen.remove(chosen.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the test case and output:

```
Your input
[1,2,3]
Output
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
Expected
[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

Comment: you could go to the tab "Discuss", there are lots of implementations in Java. You could learn from it.

Comment: @SergeyChepurnov Yeah I know there are a lot of implementations on Leetcode, but the problem I have here is not limited to the context of this question. I would like to know the general approach for me to add subsets to a result set for a recursion problem. It seems that having a global variable would not work, but I can't figure out the way to do it by passing the result list to the function as an extra parameter.

Comment: Answer? [a Java algorithm solution for subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207299/a-java-algorithm-solution-for-subsets/43209149#43209149).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
result.add(chosen);
```

basically you add `chosen` in `result` and then proceed to edit it in the next iterations. What you want to do is create a new list like so

```
result.add(new ArrayList<>(chosen));
```

EDIT: When you do `result.add(chosen);` you might think you store an arraylist `chosen` in `result`. But in fact you store the reference to the arraylist which `chosen` contains as its value. Adding a rough diagram to make things more clear

[image]

You might think `chosen` stores an entire ArrayList in itself but in reality, it just stores the reference to the arraylist which is stored in the java heap. When you make changes in `chosen` the changes will reflect at every place where the reference to this arraylist is stored, in your case it is in `result`.

Comment: Thanks! That works. So the mistake I made was that I modified ```chosen``` which already existed in ```result``` in the following iterations? Why would result.add() lead to direct modification though? I thought it would just keep adding new elements to a list.

Comment: It is because Java works that way. The value of `chosen` is not the arraylist but the reference to an arraylist stored in its heap. When you add `chosen` to `result` you do not store a copy of the arraylist `chosen` is pointing to but you are storing its reference. This makes the contents of `result` vulnerable to accidental changes whenver you change `chosen`.

Comment: Added more details in answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call return.add(chosen) you pass your chosen list to a outer list, not the inner one.

```
result.get(indexOfOuterList).add(chosen)
```

above code should work.

That's my first reply ever, sorry I tried my best. 
Let me know if I was right/wrong

Comment: result is ```List<List<Integer>>```, and I am adding List<Integer> to it. I am not sure what inner list and outer list you are referring to. @ashvin 's answer works.